# Ring: is there a way to manage http requests from the same client ip asynchronously?

Tags: clojure, ring

so that the following request will be put into a queue and wont process until the response of predecessor is sent?

I am trying to write to the database and then quickly after, allow the user to query and update his/her recent inserted document

Comment: why 'asynchronously'? It sounds like you want them to be sequential and ordered (serialised) from your description, which is different from asynchronously, which implies no fixed execution order.

Comment: apologies . asynchronous in that i dont want the two requests to be processing at the same time. id like the first http request from client a to finish processing and send the response to client a before it starts processing the second request from client a (regardless of what url path that client a hits for the first or second request)

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to avoid Read after Write hazards (to use a CPU analogy).

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [core.async](https://github.com/clojure/core.async) and [cljs-http](https://github.com/r0man/cljs-http).

You need to create a confirmation-channel with `(chan)`, write your database-write function with a callback that will put `>!` a signal into the confirmation-channel.

```
(defn database-write [data db-params callback]
    ;Do stuff
    (callback status-of-the-computation))

(def confirmation-chan (chan))

;First operation
(go 
   (database-write ;data ;db-params 
         (fn [x] (>! confirmation-chan x))))

;Second operation
(go 
   (when (<! confirmation-chan) 
       (http/post "http://example.com" {:form-params {:key1 [1 2 3] :key2 "value2"}})))
```

The second operation won't start until the first one completes.